# two urls one multilingual site with Joomla and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, multilingual, joomla3.1

I have built a multilingual site in Joomla! 3.1.x Dutch and English, using the multilingual functions native to Joomla! 3.1.x. I have two domain names that I want to go to this site, one to the Dutch side, the other to the English side.

1. http://www.internationalerozekerk.nl
2. http://www.internationallgbtchurch.org

Number 1 should go to: index.php?lang=nl

Number 2 should go to: index.php?lang=en

In the .htaccess I have added this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^internationallgbtchurch.org [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) ^internationalerozekerk.nl/index.php?lang=en$1 [L,R=301]
```

This redirects the English URL to internationalerozekerk.nl/index.php?lang=en. However, the address bar still reads: internationalerozekerk.nl/index.php?lang=en and not internationallgbtchurch.org

I haven't found anything to make the two URLs stay in the address bar.

Any suggestions?

Thanx,

Thom

Comment: Do both sites point to the same server and document root?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules instead for internal redirects:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?internationallgbtchurch\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?lang=en [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?internationalerozekerk\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?lang=nl [L,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the hostname and the `R` flag and remove the `$1`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^internationallgbtchurch.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?lang=en [L,QSA]
```

For the other site:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^internationallgbtchurch.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?lang=nl [L,QSA]
```

Adding the `$1` at the end appends the request URI, which will completely mess up the query string. If you want the path to be sent as another param, then you need to be explicit about it (for example, "path"):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^internationallgbtchurch.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?lang=en&path=$1 [L,QSA]
```